# Ideal of the union of two skew lines in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let 
$$
L_{1}=V(X_{0},X_{1})\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{3},
$$
$$
L_{2}=V(X_{2},X_{3})\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{3}.
$$
I want to prove that 
$$
I(L_{1}\cup L_{2})=(X_{0}X_{2},X_{0}X_{3},X_{1}X_{2},X_{1}X_{3}).
$$
I kown that 
$$
I(L_{1} \cup L_{2})=I(L_{1})\cap I(L_{2})=(X_{0},X_{1})\cap(X_{2},X_{3}),
$$
but I am not able to prove
$$
(X_{0},X_{1})\cap(X_{2},X_{3})=(X_{0}X_{2},X_{0}X_{3},X_{1}X_{2},X_{1}X_{3}).
$$
It is clear that
$$
(X_{0},X_{1})\cap(X_{2},X_{3})\supseteq (X_{0}X_{2},X_{0}X_{3},X_{1}X_{2},X_{1}X_{3}),
$$
but the other content is harder. How could we do it?

Answer (score 2):

The generators of the intersection of two monomial ideals can be found by taking the least common multiples of generators of the two ideals; see [here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/the-intersection-of-two-monomial-ideals-is-a-monomial-ideal/).